# Paint-like graphical editor for Debian?

Tags: debian, images, image-editor

I'm looking for simple graphical editor for Debian to make pixel art. It has to have pixel grid, be able to draw simple shapes and right-click ideally should apply secondary color (unlike gimp, which is almost ok, but has context menu on right click and is not quite simple when it comes to drawing a rectangle). MS Paint fit the bill on Win, but there are no exact clones(?) of it for Debian 9.

Comment: `xpaint` started in 1992 still works for me.

Comment: Thanks for answers, gentlemen. Krita looks good, but is a bit overkill. I use Gnome, so KolourPaint isn't a lightweight choice as well. Pinta (requires libmono) and xpaint win this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pinta](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/pinta):

```
apt install pinta
```

> Features include:
>
> - Adjustments (Auto level, Black and White, Sepia, …)
> - Effects (Motion blur, Glow, Warp, …)
> - Multiple layers
> - Unlimited undo/redo
> - Drawing tools (Paintbrush, Pencil, Shapes, …)

Including a pixel grid

Answer (score 0):

You seem to look for a basic tool and don't need the power of gimp. I'm happ with [`KolourPaint`](http://kolourpaint.org/) for this kind of task and it should serve you well, especially if you use kde.

Answer (score 0):

Krita gets most votes as an alternative on https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-paint/?platform=linux